# Angular 7 - Inject new CSS to Component SCSS file

Tags: angular, sass, angular7

Suppose I dynamically inject new HTML in the DOM.

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlCode | sanitizeHtml">
...
</div>
```

Within Tyescript:

```
htmlCode : string = '<svg class = "foobar"'>....'
```

How can I dynamically add a new class (in this case foobar) to the components scss file? Note that the class name can be different each time so I can't hard code it in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the class using [[ngClass]](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) like this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlCode | sanitizeHtml" [ngClass]="dynamicClass">
...
</div>
```

Then in your ts file:

```
htmlCode : string = '<svg class = "foobar"'>....'
dynamicClass: string = 'yourClassName';
```

Finally, if you want to set the styles dynamically, you can use [[ngStyle]](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) like this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlCode | sanitizeHtml" [ngClass]="dynamicClass" [ngStyle]="dynamicStyle">
...
</div>
```

Then in your ts file:

```
htmlCode : string = '<svg class = "foobar"'>....'
dynamicClass: string = 'yourClassName';
dynamicStyle: string = {
    'color': 'red'
  }
```

If you want to use a parameter or variable to set a style property you can do this:

```
setCustomColor(color: string): {
      dynamicStyle: string = {
        'color': `${color}`
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add this to your component and add any styles you want in your scss file

```
@Component({   ...   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, })
```

Comment: But how do I add the styles?